# Is there something similar like Chrome's network tab to spy android app traffic?

Tags: android, wireshark

I'm looking for some tool where I can see what traffic / requests android apps do. I check out [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) but for me it looked more like I can spy the lower layers. I would love to view the application layer.

- Does anybody have experience with this problem?
- Are there any tools which allow doing this?
- Is this even possible from an application point of view?